# Angular Routes and Rails Partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

Hi have an angluar route that looks like this

```
app.config ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider.when("/",
    {
      templateUrl: "assets/pages/partials/home_controls.html"
      controller: MapCtrl
    }
  ).when("/products/business",
    {
      templateUrl: "../assets/pages/partials/business_controls.html"
      controller: MapCtrl
    }
  ).when("/products/search",
    {
      templateUrl: "../assets/pages/partials/search_controls.html"
      controller: MapCtrl
    }
  )
```

Its works really well. And loads the partials inside an

When these pages load from the address input or page refresh they load fine

However if I have a link controlled by a Rails view for example, it only loads the AngularJS Partial and does not change the Rails page. For example:

```
<%= render :partial => "pages/partials/map"%>
```

The Angular code is loading inside that partrial, other surrounding layouts control the Nav's etc...

Its odd because a link to a page only loads Angular but a fresh address loads everything okay

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it happens because of

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Are you sure your browser realy asks your rails server to give it the page?